# Call to a member function replicate() on null / Clone an Product from DB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want Duplicate an Product in my DB with an new Product ID.

My index.blade:

```
<form action="{{ route('cloneproduct',['uid'=>$product->uniqueid]) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

{{csrf_field()}}

<button type="submit" name="button" class="cloneproduct">Clone</button>

</form>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('cloneproduct/{uniqueid}','ProfileController@CloneItem')->name('cloneproduct');
```

Controller:

```
public function CloneItem($uniqueid)
    {
        $product = Product::find($uniqueid);
        $new_product = $product->replicate();
        $new_product->push(); 
       return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Error:

> Call to a member function replicate() on null

Whats the Problem? Its not null in my DB..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the error because there is no row with `id = $uniqueId` in the table:

```
Product::find($uniqueid);
```

`find()` method uses the primary key to find a row. So, if you've changed `id` to something else, you need to define a `$primaryKey` property in the `Product` model:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'uid';
```

You can also check if `find()` doesn't return an object:

```
if (is_null($product))
```

Comment: Also 0 Results.. ID are exist 100%

Comment: @markussibert as I said in my answer, you need to define a primary key if it's no `id`. Or do this `Product::where('uid', $uniqueId)->first()` instead of `find()`.

Comment: now i get this error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$newproduct' (T_VARIABLE)" :(

Comment: Add `;` to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks man! Works Great! :) i have also must change "uid" to "uniqueId". Can i also generate an new uniqueId? Because if the Products have the same uniqueId (Thats my Product URL) all Items have the same Links.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [findOrFail()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) instead for this case.

```
public function CloneItem($uniqueid)
    {
        $product = Product::findOrFail($uniqueid);
        $new_product = $product->replicate();
        $new_product->push(); 
       return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Comment: there is no Product with that id. Make sure u have a product with that Id and that primary key its unchanged. If its changed then you must specify that in Product Model `protected $primaryKey = 'yourKey'; `

Comment: i dont understand this.. I dont have changed the ID and the Product with ID are exist.

Comment: okay then you do not have a Product with that id on database. Go manually check the database if you have a product with that id. And tell us what is your primary key on Products.

Comment: Yes of course i have id and i see it also on my Index page. I want add now an Clone Button behind the Product. What you mean with Primary Key?

Comment: @markussibert just go to the table Product and show me the column names. Id your $uniqueId lets say its 2 then in database you must have a product with id (primary key) 2 otherwise you will get No query results meaning you do not have that product in database.

Comment: Its "uniqueid", the same as works for all other my Controller commands..

Comment: @markussibert beacuse this response from Laravel  No query results for model it is telling us that you do not have a product with $productId on databse.

Comment: @markussibert  do you have a column name 'uniqueid' in table Products. If you have then go to Product model and add this protected $primaryKey = 'uniqueid';